# PHP 5.6 removed features

Tags: php

As of 10th July 2016, support for PHP5.5 has stopped, as seen on http://php.net/supported-versions.php. I have therefore been tasked with upgrading a legacy system to 5.6. My question is, what features have been **removed** in 5.6? I have looked through http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php, which does list newly deprecated features, as well as backward incompatible changes, but no removed features. Have no features actually been removed in 5.6?

Comment: Nothing was removed in PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.5 to 5.6 was a relatively minor update (compared to PHP 5.6 to 7.0). Nothing (as far as the PHP core is concerned) was removed between versions 5.5 and 5.6. If there had been, they would be listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php

Incompatible changes are MUST CHECK items when upgrading to a new version. If you were doing a bare-bones / quick-and-dirty migration this is what you want to check. Granted you should always read through all changes noted in migration guides so that you know what was changed and will allow you to learn what is new and what changes have occurred throughout the extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading up and couldn't find removed features, but wanted some confirmation.